# how to run a benchmark only on core 0 of the cpu (single-core)?

Tags: ubuntu, cpu, benchmarking, perf

What should I do in Ubuntu when we want to run a benchmark only on core 0 of the cpu for example?

So that when I run perf stat, the number of instructions does not change.

And on the other hand, do not run another program on core 0?

thanks

Comment: `taskset -c 0 perf stat ...`  The number of user-space instructions should be essentially constant anyway, though, with `perf stat --all-user ...`.  If you don't use that, you're counting interrupt handlers as well.  `perf` virtualizes the HW performance counters across context switches; you don't need to pin tasks just to get accurate counts.  It does make sure the scheduler doesn't migrate it to another core in the middle of a run, though.